# how to add multiple jars in spark submit?

Tags: apache-spark

```
--jars ${BASE_DIR}/bin/jtds-1.3.1.jar,${BASE_DIR}/bin/jconn3-6.10.jar \
  --driver-class-path net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver \
```

is this the correct way of adding multiple jars in spark submit shel????l

Answer (score 0):

According to the [manual](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) yes it is the correct way.  It would be helpful if you also posted the error/behavior you are experiencing that is making you question it?  Alternatively you may also include these libraries in your application jar.  It also look like you are misusing the **--driver-class-path net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver** parameter, it is not there to specify the database driver, it is there to modify the class path of the SparkDriver component.  Your JDBC connection string should be specified in the application itself see [SPARK JDBC DOC](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html) for more details.

SIDE NOTE: However depending on your spark application you may want workers to have access to the DB driver as well for parallelized access.